# How to implement something like PHP's http_build_query and the reverse in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<?php
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data);
/* Output：
      foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
*/
```

How to do similar thing in javascript,say, get the **query string** from the **array** ,and convert the **array** to **query string**?

**UPDATE**

the jquery plugin is not working:

```
var fromVar = $.query.load('?cow=milk')
fromVar.set('first', 'value'); 
fromVar.toString()
```

It outputs `?cow=milk` while I want it to be `?cow=milk&first=value`

Comment: Might this help?
http://phpjs.org/functions/http_build_query:428

Comment: No, I can't import a totally new giant for this only functionality!

Comment: That function doesn't have any dependencies, so you can just copy and paste it (following the license).

Comment: Then it's good! But how can I convert the query string back to an array/object then?

Comment: In the related functions list of the PHP documentation for http_build_query, you can find parse_str, which does what you want.

Google is your friend (again...): http://www.google.com/search?q=parse_str+javascript

Answer (score 30):

If you're using jQuery, then you can use the [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) function:

```
var obj = { "foo":"bar", "baz":"boom", "php":"hypertext processor" };
var str = jQuery.param(obj);
alert(str); // should be "foo=bar&baz=boom&php=hypertext+processor"
```

It can serialise some complex arrays too.

Comment: @Shea If the answer doesn't solve your problem, vote it down.

Comment: You named it `var array`, it should've been `var obj`,

Comment: Well spotted - it only took someone 7 years :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `URLSearchParams` class:

```
var searchParametersData = {
  "foo": "baz",
  "bar": "foo"
};

var searchParameters = new URLSearchParams();

Object.keys(searchParametersData).forEach(function(parameterName) {
  searchParameters.append(parameterName, searchParametersData[parameterName]);
});

console.log(searchParameters.toString()); // foo=baz&bar=foo
```

To get the parameters object from a search parameter string, use this:

```
var searchParametersString = "foo=baz&bar=foo";

var searchParameters = new URLSearchParams(searchParametersString);

var searchParametersData = {};

for (var searchParameter of searchParameters) {
  searchParametersData[searchParameter[0]] = searchParameter[1];
}

console.log(searchParametersData); // {foo: "baz", bar: "foo"}
```

Comment: Hi, in case of return a typeof Object? what best practice? Eg:       Object.keys(searchParametersData).forEach(function (parameterName) {
        if (typeof searchParametersData[parameterName] !== 'object') {
          searchParameters.append(parameterName, searchParametersData[parameterName])
        } else {
          let objeto = searchParametersData[parameterName]
          Object.keys(objeto).forEach(function (parameterName) {
            searchParameters.append(parameterName, objeto[parameterName])
          })
        }
      })

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you can simply use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) constructor on your object.

```js
const data = {
  "test1": 1,
  "test2": "two",
  "test3": 3,
};

const params = new URLSearchParams(data);

console.log(params.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I use following javascript counterpart of PHP's *http_build_query*:

**Function definition**:

```
const http_build_query = (dataToSend) => {
    let formBody = []
    for (let key in dataToSend) {
      let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(key)
      let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(dataToSend[key])
      formBody.push(encodedKey + '=' + encodedValue)
    }
    return formBody.join('&')
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let dataToSend = {user_id:123, name:'Your name'}
const formBody = http_build_query(dataToSend)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the jQuery [query plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/345).  It's pretty intuitive.  You can use get and set accessors to read and modify the query string:

```
var cow = $.query.get('cow');
$.query.set('cow', 'goat');
```

You can create a new query object from an existing string:

```
var fromVar = $.query.load('?cow=milk')
var cow = fromVar.get('cow'); // milk
```

You can also create an empty object:

```
var newQ = $.query.empty();
newQ = newQ.set('first', 'value'); // "?first=value"
```

Comment: No, I don't want it to get query string from location.href, but from a specific javascript variable.

Comment: You can create it from an existing string.

Comment: There was a bug above, which I fixed.  I made a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jwCpg/ .