# JavaScript implementation for http_build_query — Generate URL-encoded query string?

Tags: javascript, rest

Looking for JavaScript implementation for similar php function [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) - send nested JavaScript object as a request parameter in GET/POST method.

Sample object:

```
var params = {
  codes: [
    {
        id: 1212,
        name: "log",
    },
    {
        id: 123,
        name: "console",
    }
  ],
  ajaxsettings : { "ak1" : "v1", "ak2" : "v2"},
  uisettings : { "ui1" : "v1", "ui22" : "v2"},
};
```

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2962972/215552 Also, a quick search yielded http://locutus.io/php/url/http_build_query/. Please do some research before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes sure.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is allowed to be used you can utilize [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

```
var query = $.param(params);
```

```js
var params = {
  codes: [
    {
        id: 1212,
        name: "log",
    },
    {
        id: 123,
        name: "console",
    }
  ],
  ajaxsettings : { "ak1" : "v1", "ak2" : "v2"},
  uisettings : { "ui1" : "v1", "ui22" : "v2"},
};

var query = $.param(params);
console.log(query);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```